# Neo4J create relationship hangs on remote, but node creation succeeds

Tags: java, neo4j

My relationship creation hangs, yet the nodes underneath manage to persist to my remote client.

```
public class Baz 
{  
    private static enum CustomRelationships implements RelationshipType {
        CATEGORY
    }

     public void foo()  
     {    
         RestGraphDatabse db = new RestGraphDatabase("http://remoteIp:7474/db/data",username,password);
         Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
         try{  
         Node a = db.createNode();
            a.setProperty("foo", "foo");  // finishes
            Node b = db.createNode();
            b.setProperty("bar", "bar"); //finishes
            a.createRelationshipTo(b, CustomRelationships .CATEGORY); // hangs
            System.out.println("Finished relationship");
            tx.success();
        } finally {
            tx.finish();
        }
     }  
}
```

And I cannot figure out why.  There is no stack and the connection doesn't time out.

```
a.createRelationshipTo(b, DynamicRelationshipType.withName("CATEGORY"));
```

also hangs

This query executes correctly from the admin shell:

> start first=node(19), second=node(20)  Create first-[r:RELTYPE {
>   linkage : first.Baz + '<-->' +  second.BazCat }]->second return r

Yet when run in this fashion:

```
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("start first=node("
                    + entityNode.getId() + "), second=node("
                    + categoryNode.getId() + ") "
                    + " Create first-[r:RELTYPE { linkage : first.Baz"
                    + " + '<-->' +  second.BazCat" + " }]->second return r");
```

Also hangs.

Comment: Transaction tx = rest.beginTx(); you are starting transaction on rest variable, it must be on db variable right?

Comment: @RameshK oops bad cross editing.

Comment: @RameshK it is fixed now.

Comment: If you replace `CustomRelationship.CATEGORY` with `DynamicRelationshipType.withName("CATEGORY))`, does it still hang?

Comment: @WernerVesterås yes still hangs

Comment: Your transactional code will not work because you're connecting to a REST database. You can just have one transaction per REST call. That's why your nodes are created and your relationship aren't. No idea why the relationship creation hangs though...

Comment: @tstorms I think I may be misunderstanding what you meant.  I do have just one transaction per rest call

Comment: @Woot4Moo Yes, exactly. There can only be a single transaction per HTTP call. I've read that the Neo4j team is thinking about implementing a scenario where multiple HTTP calls span a single transaction, but for now you're out of luck. Still, no idea what's causing you're application to hang...

Comment: @tstorms ah yes.  Working with one of the neo4j guys now to see why my environment is so special

Comment: @Woot4Moo Great! Please post the solution once you've found it. Btw, have you tried working with an EmbeddedGraphDatabase (or ImpermanentGraphDatabase in unit tests)?

Comment: @tstorms embedded.  What is this ImpermanentGraphDatabase?

Comment: The ImpermanentGraphDatabase is a database meant to be used in unit tests. It will always be empty on start. If you've already tried the embedded datababse, then this won't work either (because it extends EmbeddedGraphDatabase).

Comment: @tstorms google group discussion: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/neo4j/DkiyTop7p1w/discussion

Answer (score 1):

1. There are no real transactions over rest.
2. It is a bug in the Java-Rest-Binding that internal threads are not started as daemon threads. It actually doesn't hang just the program is not ended. 
   You can `System.exit(0)` to end the program as a workaround.

Comment: Indeed, I do appreciate you working on that one.  I imagine we will start running into each other a bit more often.